# How do I output a file to a specific directory?

Tags: perl

I would like to have the files that I am creating to be output into the directory I created in my perl script.

I can create the directory

```
use File::Path;

$dir = "foo/";
mkpath($dir);
```

and my files

```
$FILE = "output.txt";
unless(open $filehandle, ">", $FILE){
  die "\nUnable to create $FILE:\n$!";
}
printf $filehandle "writing stuff to my file\n";
printf $filehandle "and some more stuff\n";
close($filehandle);
```

Everything works fine except I was the files to be output into the directory I made earlier in the script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did your file gets created now??

Comment: Why mkpath instead of mkdir? Either way, check whether the function succeeded. If you do need File::Path, use make_path() if available (in later versions). Include "$!" in your open() or die error message.

Comment: Ok, mkpath() does croak on error, so checking its success is not necessary. Other comments stand.

Comment: @RohitJain, In the directory the script is located. I just wanted to create a new directory because my actual script generates a large number of files.

Comment: @runrig, I'm new to perl and was wondering what is the advantage of using "$!"?

Comment: Then you can create a new dir by using `mkdir()` under the `current directory` and then create a file in it.. As in my post below..

Comment: $! is used when you use `die` while opening file.. It contains system related error when file fails to open.. (You always use `$!` at the end of your `die` to give error information to use..

Comment: @runrig, I used mkpath because the example I was referencing used mkpath. make_path() did not work for me, so i must an earlier version.

Comment: $! should also be used in error messages for mkdir().

Comment: If you are only creating one new level of directory, then mkdir() works fine. mkpath() is generally for /multiple/levels/of/new/directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do what you're asking:

```
$FILE = "$dir/output.txt";
unless(open $filehandle, ">", $FILE){
  die "\nUnable to create $FILE:\n$!";
}
printf $filehandle "writing stuff to my file\n";
printf $filehandle "and some more stuff\n";
close($filehandle);
```

You need to specify the path where you want your file to be written. You could use either an absolute path or a relative path, starting from your current working directory.

Comment: @darch, I just copied the code the user had posted, changing it to accomplish what he wants... I didn't know I had to optimize it. My answer fits the question...

Comment: Your answer should model good code or at least not-bad code.  2-arg `open` is wrong.

Comment: That's a bit harsh, but in this particular case I agree (catenate `>` and the filename? Really!)

Comment: @darch, Sorry, I do not agree. The question was "How do I output a file to a specific directory?" and not "Is this code correct and beautiful to see? Does it respect standards?". I could change it to a cleaner one, but the questioner will just spot the change in path (as his question was for that) and will not question himself about why I'm using a different syntax. I don't even think a question like this is the right place to explain in the answer these things. Cheers.

Comment: @Zagorax.. Now you are wrong.. A question being asked for different reason doesn't justify your saying that "A better code is not needed", just because OP will not see them..

Comment: @zagorax You are of course free to disagree.  I think your answer is a bad answer and have voted accordingly.

Comment: @ikegami Where you the one who made the edit that removed "unless"? If so, why would you even have "unless"?

Comment: I removed it because I added a needed `my`, and using an `if` or `unless` block would break that. The edit was a bad edit because that code was copied from the OP. I came in from the review tool of the web site, from where it can be hard to grasp the context of the situation.

Comment: As is, that code has two scoping errors. Neither `$FILE` nor `$filehandle` is scoped. `use strict;` will show those errors. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use chdir to change to the directory, or prepend the directory to the file name:

```
chdir($dir) or die "Failed to cd to $dir: $!";
# or
$FILE = "$dir/output.txt";
```

But don't do both.

Answer (score 2):

```
use File::Spec::Functions;
my $dir = "/somedir";
my $FILE = "output.txt";

my $path = catfile($dir, $FILE)
my $filehandle

unless(open $filehandle, '>',  $path){
  die "\nUnable to create $FILE\n";
}
close($filehandle)
```

There is not much of a difference from others, but you can use `catfile` to make a path according to the current OS. You don't want to change the way you build path when you port your code..

Also, using `lexical` filehandler is a better option than using Bareword (FILE)..

Comment: @darch.. What do you suggest?? I am new to perl, so am aware of this kind of open only.. Are you saying to use 3-arg open?? '<' for read as 2nd arg?? That I knew.. But for reading it's default thats why I didn't use..

Comment: Yes, use 3-arg `open` even for reading.  2-arg `open` has problems (consider, for example, trying to open a file with the name `>badly-named file<`) and should not be used.

Comment: I didn't understand.. `<badly-named file>` -> Can you give examples.. One benefit of 3-arg open I know is that, it allows us add extra information along with `mode` just by using a `:`, like `>:encoding(utf:8)`..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17259/discussion-between-darch-and-rohit-jain)